# ELM/Haskell : use Regular expression(Regex) to search a String and render Html view

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, elm

what I am trying to do is to parse **string** using regular expression and get **Html** element as output so the function signature should be as following:

```
parse : String -> Html Msg
```

before we dive in the code let us take an example how the code should behave in order to have a clear idea, given a the below string as below :

**input** : hello (!BOLD!) I Am a bold text (!BOLD!)bla bla la

**expected output** : div [ ][ text "hello", b [ ][ text "I Am a  bold text" ] , text "bla la la"] ]

in order to achieve this goal, I have used the regex library provided in ELM package

```
replace : HowMany -> Regex -> (Match -> String) -> String -> String
```

on top of the above function, i created the 2 function listed here after :

```
myReplace   str expression =
  replace (All)  ( regex expression )   matchToString  str
 --myreplace "hello (!BOLD!) bold (!BOLD!) " "(!BOLD!)"  == "hello b[][] hello"
```

with the below helper function, this function take a Match and specify the start and the end for the regular expression

```
matchToString : Match -> String
matchToString match =
  case  match.number `rem` 2  of
    0 ->"]" -- mtaches the close bracket
    _ -> "B [][" --mtaches the open bracket
```

but what I want to get is : `div [][text "hello", b[][text "bold"]]`

how could I improve my code and write the full parser? or how could I achieve the same purpose in haskell?

reference : [elm regex source](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular Expressions start to lose their power and become overly complex in cases like this. Instead, I recommend looking into [Parser Combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator) which are much more powerful while being easier to maintain and reason about.

For this example I'll be using the [Bogdanp/elm-combine](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Bogdanp/elm-combine/latest/Combine) package.

Here we'll build up a parser that takes a string and assumes it's unstyled until it hits `(!BOLD!)` and will remain bold until it finds another `(!BOLD!)` entry. The output will be a list of tuples of characters and whether they are `Unstyled` or `Bold`. *caveat: there are probably more concise combinators to achieve this but I'm relatively new to the art*

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Combine exposing (..)
import Combine.Char exposing (..)
import Combine.Infix exposing (..)
import String
import List.Extra exposing (groupWhile)

type Style
  = Unstyled
  | Bold

styleParser : Bool -> Parser (List (Char, Style))
styleParser bolded =
  let
    style = if bolded then Bold else Unstyled
  in
    (end `andThen` always (succeed []))
      <|> (string "(!BOLD!)" `andThen` \_ -> styleParser (not bolded))
      <|> (anyChar
           `andThen` \c -> styleParser bolded
           `andThen` \cs -> (succeed ((c, style) :: cs)))
```

The result of that parser for the example `"a(!BOLD!)b(!BOLD!)c"` would contain the list `[('a', Unstyled), ('b', Bold), ('c', Unstyled)]`, so we need to do some mapping and folding in order to turn that into a list of `Html msg` values:

```elm
htmlParser : Parser (List (Html msg))
htmlParser =
  styleParser False
    `andThen` (succeed << foldStyledHtml)

foldStyledHtml : List (Char, Style) -> List (Html msg)
foldStyledHtml chars =
  let
    foldSingleStyledHtml =
      List.foldr (\(c, s) (cs, _) -> (c :: cs, s)) ([], Unstyled)
        >> \(chars, style) ->
          let str = String.fromList chars
          in case style of
              Unstyled -> text str
              Bold -> b [] [ text str ]
  in
    groupWhile (\a b -> snd a == snd b) chars
      |> List.map foldSingleStyledHtml
```

You can then output some example text using the following:

```elm
main =
  case parse htmlParser testInput of
    (Ok htmls, _) -> div [] htmls
    (Err err, _) -> div [ style [("color", "red")] ] [ text <| toString <| err]
```

I've posted the full source of this [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/2754fdc1ed15356074dc09e34962819b). You'll also need the package `elm-community/list-extra`. Hope this helps!