# functional programming : understand parser combinator

Tags: elm

I was trying to solve a problem using a parser combinator. I tried the following:

**Note**: the below code uses the [combinator library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Bogdanp/elm-combine/2.2.1/Combine)

```
styleParserItalic : Bool -> Parser ( List (List Char , Style))
styleParserItalic bolded =
let
style = if bolded then Italic else Unstyled
 in
 (end `andThen` always (  succeed ( [] )))
 <|> (string "(!ITALIC!)" `andThen`  \_ -> styleParserItalic ( not bolded )   ) 
 <|> ( anyChar `andThen` \c -> styleParserItalic bolded `andThen` \cs -> succeed ((c :: [],style) :: cs) )
```

I am struggling to understand how this parser runs since the `styleParserItalic` parser is called before the parser succeeds.

Could someone explain how the parser works when it is given a string of characters?

If someone is interested in the purpose of the parser and the full code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912233/elm-haskell-use-regular-expressionregex-to-search-a-string-and-render-html-v/37945519#37945519) is my previous question.

**Here is what I have understood thus far**

The parser will check first if it is the end of a line , if not it will try to parser the string `(!ITALIC!)` if that the case then it will call the parser with with parameter True or false (if false then will makes it true ..)

If the parser does not find the the string (!ITALIC!) it will try to parse any character then it will call the parser again.

What confuses me is that the parser will keep calling itself as long as it succeeds with parsing any character!

**edit :*** *NOTE THE BELOW IS NOT A PART OF THE QUESTION, JUST TO SHARE THE CODE IF SOMEONE IS INTERESTED*

thanks for all responses, I have updated the parser to parse Bold italic underline..., as per the below screen shot[image]

```
type Style = Bold| Unstyled | Italic | Coded | Lined | Titled | Marked     | Underline

styleParser : Bool ->Bool ->Bool ->Bool-> Bool-> Bool->Bool
                                -> Parser ( List (List Char ,     (Style,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style)))
                                --(bold,italic ,code,line ,Titled,mark)
styleParser bolded italiced coded lined titled marked  underlined=
  let
    style = (
     if bolded     then Bold      else Unstyled
    ,if italiced   then Italic    else Unstyled
    ,if coded      then Coded     else Unstyled
    ,if lined      then Lined     else Unstyled
    ,if titled     then Titled    else Unstyled
    ,if marked     then Marked    else Unstyled
    ,if underlined then Underline else Unstyled
    )
  in
    (end `andThen` always ( succeed ( [] )))
    <|> (string "//"  `andThen` \_ -> styleParser  bolded      italiced         coded       lined       titled       marked        (not underlined))
    <|> (string "**"  `andThen` \_ -> styleParser (not bolded) italiced        coded       lined       titled       marked        underlined)
    <|> (string "*"   `andThen` \_ -> styleParser bolded       (not italiced)  coded       lined       titled       marked        underlined)
    <|> (string "`"   `andThen` \_ -> styleParser bolded       italiced        (not coded) lined       titled       marked        underlined)
    <|> (string "/br" `andThen` \_ -> styleParser bolded       italiced        coded       (not lined) titled       marked        underlined)
    <|> (string "/*"  `andThen` \_ -> styleParser bolded       italiced        coded       lined       (not titled) marked        underlined)
    <|> (string "{-"  `andThen` \_ -> styleParser bolded       italiced        coded       lined       titled       (not marked)  underlined)
    <|> ( anyChar     `andThen` \c -> styleParser bolded       italiced         coded       lined       titled       marked        underlined  `andThen`    \cs -> succeed ((c :: [],style) :: cs) )


foldStyleHtml : List ( List Char , (    Style,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style) ) -> List (Html Msg)
foldStyleHtml lst =
  List.map styleToHtml lst


styleToHtml : ( List Char, (Style ,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style,Style)) -> Html Msg
styleToHtml (a,b) =
  case b of
    (Bold,Italic,_,_,_,_,Unstyled)       -> strong [] [em [][ text   (String.fromList a)]]
    (Bold,Italic,_,_,_,_,Underline)      -> u[][ strong [] [em [][ text (String.fromList a)]]]
    (Bold,Unstyled,_,_,_,_,Underline)    -> u[][ strong [] [text (String.fromList a)]]
    (Unstyled,Italic,_,_,_,_,Underline)  -> u[][ em     [] [text (String.fromList a)]]
(Unstyled,Italic,_,_,_,_,_)          -> em[] [text (String.fromList a)]
(Bold,Unstyled,_,_,_,_,_)            -> strong [][ text (String.fromList a)]
 (_,_,Coded,_,_,_,_)                  -> code   [codeStyle ][text     (String.fromList a)]
(_,_,_,Lined,_,_,_)                  -> br [][text " "]
  --  (_,_,_,_,Titled,_,_)                 -> div [][text (String.fromList a)]
    (_,_,_,_,_,Marked,_)                 -> mark [][text (String.fromList a)]
    (_,_,_,_,_,_,Underline)              -> u [][text (String.fromList a)]
   (_,_,_,_,_,_,_)                      -> text  (String.fromList a)

htmlParser : Parser  (List (Html Msg))
htmlParser =
 styleParser False False False False False False False `andThen` (succeed << foldStyleHtml )

runParser : Parser (List (Html Msg)) -> String -> Html Msg
runParser parser str                                    =
  case parse parser str of
    (Ok htmls,_)-> div [] htmls
    (Err err, _) -> div [ style [("color", "red")] ] [ text <| toString <| err]
```

Comment: I would humbly mention [a blot post I wrote a few years ago](https://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/08/16/easy-parsing-in-scala/) as an introduction to parser combinators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parser combinators (generally) consume input as they succeed. In this library, if `string "(!ITALIC!)"` fails, it will not consume any input. Since the `<|>` combinator is used, it then tries to use the next part of the code that starts with `anyChar`.

When `anyChar` succeeds, it consumes that single character and captures it in `c` after `andThen`. Then the remaining string (everything but the character captured by `anyChar`) is then "crawled" when the recursive call to `styleParserItalic bolded` is made. That second `andThen` captures the output of the recursive combinator into `cs` and prepends the captured character onto the rest of the list of characters from the recursive call.

I think the important part to remember is that the combinators consume input as they succeed and (generally) don't consume input when they fail.

Comment: Thanks, so on every call for the recursive  styleParserItalic it will pass its result to cs and run the succeed parser or will it wait for all recursive call to finish (all character parsed) then will parse the result to cs?

Comment: Since it's recursive, it will recurse to the last character of the string before returning up the chain. That's why there is the first combinator of `end`, which checks for an end of input and returns the empty list if matched (without `end` it would spin forever). The recursive tree then folds up and builds up the list by prepending each `c` onto `cs` returned from the recursive call.

Comment: lets say I am trying to parser the String "ABC", the final result should be succeed (('A',Unstyled) :: (B ,Unstyled) ::  (C ,Unstyled) :: always (succeed ([])) )  right ? so how always (succeed ([]))  is added to a list of tuples?

Comment: `succeed` is a function which takes a raw value and puts it in the context of a parser (the Parser type is a monad even though elm shies away from the term). That means the resulting list, in the context of a Parser, is  `('A',Unstyled) :: ('B' ,Unstyled) ::  ('C' ,Unstyled) :: []`, or using list syntax, is  `[('A',Unstyled), ('B' ,Unstyled), ('C' ,Unstyled)]`

Answer (score 2):

First a few simplications...

**(1)** Every element of the inner List in the signature:

```
styleParserItalic : Bool -> Parser ( List (List Char , Style))
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

is just a single character. By just removing `:: []` from the last line,

```
 <|> ... `andThen` \cs -> succeed ((c ,style) :: cs) )
                                    ^^^
                                      removed `:: []`
```

you can make it have this signature.

**(2)** Note that the `bolded` argument only affects the Style - it has not effect on control flow. It really should be called `italic` since the style appearing in the output is `Italic` if the argument is True and `Unstyled` otherwise.

Also note that once this parameter is set the True, it will remain True in
all subsequent recursive calls.

So now the algorithm is:

1. If at the end of the line, return the empty list.
2. If at `(!ITALIC!)`, use `Italic` for the style in the remainder of the parse.
3. Otherwise, parse a character, parse the remainder of the line and concatenate the results.

An approximate Python algorithm would be something like:

```
def parseLine(style, line):
  result = []
  while line:
    if line.startsWith('(!ITALIC!)'):
      line = line[8:]
      style = Italic
      # loop around
    else:
      result.append( (line[0], style) )
      line = line[1:]
  return result
```